# how to search a user in a bootstrap table of users?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing an application for users management with `spring mvc`. I'm using this  [bootstrap table](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/js-table-filter-simple-insensitive)  in my `jsp`page which make me do a research on the data in the table .

In my table the data of users is retreived from database . this is the code :

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <form action="#" method="get">
        <div class="input-group">
            <!-- USE TWITTER TYPEAHEAD JSON WITH API TO SEARCH -->
            <input class="form-control" id="system-search" name="q"
                placeholder="Search for" required> <span
                class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
    <table class="table table-list-search">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Surname</th>
                <th>email</th>
                <th>contact</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <c:forEach items="${listUsers}" var="user">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>${user.id}</td>
                    <td>${user.name}</td>
                    <td>${user.surname}</td>
                    <td>${user.email}</td>
                    <td>${user.contact}</td>
                    <td>
                        <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit"
                                    data-toggle="modal"
                                    onclick="location.href='<c:url value="/modifier/${user.id}" />'">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                            </button>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="delete"
                                    data-delete='${user.id}' data-toggle="modal"
                                    data-target="#confirm-delete" data-href="/supprimer/${user.id}">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                            </button>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</div>
```

and this is the script which do the research on the table :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var activeSystemClass = $('.list-group-item.active');

    //something is entered in search form
    $('#system-search')
        .keyup(function() {
            var that = this;

            // affect all table rows on in systems table
            var tableBody = $('.table-list-search tbody');
            var tableRowsClass = $('.table-list-search tbody tr');
            $('.search-sf').remove();

            tableRowsClass
                .each(function(i, val) {
                    //Lower text for case insensitive
                    var rowText = $(val).text().toLowerCase();
                    var inputText = $(that).val().toLowerCase();
                    if (inputText != '') {
                        $('.search-query-sf').remove();
                        tableBody
                            .prepend('<tr class="search-query-sf"><td colspan="6"><strong>Searching for: "'
                                + $(that).val()
                                + '"</strong></td></tr>');
                    } else {
                        $('.search-query-sf').remove();
                    }

                    if (rowText.indexOf(inputText) == -1) {
                        //hide rows
                        tableRowsClass.eq(i).hide();
                    } else {
                        $('.search-sf').remove();
                        tableRowsClass.eq(i).show();
                    }
                });
                //all tr elements are hidden
                if (tableRowsClass.children(':visible').length == 0) {
                    tableBody.append('<tr class="search-sf"><td class="text-muted" colspan="6">No entries found.</td></tr>');
                }
            });
});
```

but when I've changed to dynamic table I have this result which make the word `searching for :` repeated n times  !

[image]

I tried to change the code of the script but I failed to have the right script.
could some one help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this might be the problem

```
tableRowsClass.each(function(i, val) {
               //Lower text for case insensitive
               var rowText = $(val).text().toLowerCase();
               var inputText = $(that).val().toLowerCase();
               if (inputText != '') {
                   $('.search-query-sf').remove();
                   tableBody.prepend('<tr class="search-query-sf"><td colspan="6"><strong>Searching for: "'+ $(that).val()+ '"</strong></td></tr>');
```

`.each` means that you're adding `<tr class="search-query-sf"><td colspan="6"><strong>Searching for: "'+ $(that).val()+ '"</strong></td></tr>` to the start (because it's prepend) of your table, one for every element using `.table-list-search tbody tr`

try just moving `tableBody.prepend('<tr class="search-query-sf"><td colspan="6"><strong>Searching for: "'+ $(that).val()+ '"</strong></td></tr>');` outside of the `.each()` so that it only runs once.

Comment: thanks for your fast reply, I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. when moving that line outside of the `.each()` it don't recognize `$that.val()`  anymore

Comment: umm... okay that's a little strange... where did you move it to?

if you try putting the line directly above the start of the `.each()` method, it should still be within the scope of where you declared `that`

Comment: yeh, i just double checked one notepad++, put the line directly above the `.each` line and it should be able to see `that`

Comment: I have moved it directly above `.each` but still not working 
.... `  tableBody.prepend('<tr class="search-query-sf"><td colspan="6"><strong>Searching for: "'+ $(that).val()+ '"</strong></td></tr>');
              .each(function(i, val) {`

Comment: What about creating the line in the HTML, and using CSS to hide it until you need it? and then you can just remove that CSS class

Comment: how can we use a research action with html and css ..could you please explain more ?

Comment: I posted a new answer with an example, It's a completley different way of doing what you are trying to do. I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I echo Jamie's answer, but I'd do a bit more refactoring.

I would move the searching out into its own function and pass the required rows collection and search string into it.

I would also move the check for search text outside the `each` loop, because the value is available outside the loop and doesn't change.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var activeSystemClass = $('.list-group-item.active');
    var searchTable = function(rows, searchStr){
        var searching = false;
        rows.each(function(i, val){
            var rowText = $(val).text().toLowerCase();
            if (rowText.indexOf(searchStr) == -1) {
                //hide rows
                rows.eq(i).hide();
            } else {
                $('.search-sf').remove();
                rows.eq(i).show();
            }
            if (rows.children(':visible').length == 0) {
                tableBody.append('<tr class="search-sf"><td class="text-muted" colspan="6">No entries found.</td></tr>');
            }
        }
    };

    //something is entered in search form
    $('#system-search')
        .keyup(function() {
            var that = this;

            // affect all table rows on in systems table
            var tableBody = $('.table-list-search tbody');
            var tableRowsClass = $('.table-list-search tbody tr');
            var inputText = $(that).val();
            $('.search-sf').remove();

            if (inputText != ''){
                $('.search-query-sf').remove();
                searchTable(tableRowsClass, inputText.toLowerCase())
                tableBody.prepend('<tr class="search-query-sf"><td colspan="6"><strong>Searching for: "' + inputText + '"</strong></td></tr>');
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: what didn't work? is there an error? still duplicate the extra row? anything on the console?

Comment: in the console I had this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list ` in the 17 th  line of your code ..I've added `);` and retested again ..but I had the same issue `searching for ..xx` is repeated n times

Comment: If you can provide either a [fiddle to demonstrate](https://jsfiddle.net/user/dashboard/) or the rendered page html/code - that would be a great help.  I'll take another look later.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using javascript to create the repeating table row could be to use the `hidden` attribute and use javascript to remove that attribute whenever the `.keyup` event fires. You can then use javascript to set the value of a `span` tag with the search query. I couldn't get this example to work on jsFiddle or plunker, but i made an example. (this is pure raw JS with no styling)

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doSearch(){
      document.getElementById("searchingForRow").removeAttribute("hidden");
     document.getElementById("searching").innerHTML = document.getElementById("system-search").value
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-md-9">

<div class="input-group">
  <form>
    <div>
      <input id="system-search" placeholder="Search for" >
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="doSearch()">
                Search
            </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
      <th>email</th>
      <th>contact</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr class="search-query-sf" id="searchingForRow" hidden>
    <td colspan="6"><strong>Searching for: <span id="searching"></span></strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>An Example data this does nothing</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

this example, when the search button is clicked, removed the hidden attribute, making that row visible, and set's the span in the row to the value of the textbox.

it's essentially what you are trying to do.

with this method, it doesn't matter how many times the code to remove the `hidden` attribute is called, nothing will render more than once.